# What are things to consider when choosing a startup enviroment, u-boot vs uefi?

Tags: boot, uefi

I am very new to this world.

I have an ARM SoC and would like to choose a startup environment.

What are things to consider?

The two choices provided by the vendor are u-boot and UEFI.

Is one easier to modify than the other?

Comment: This question is very broad. I would be great, if you can add more specifics ie. what OS you plan to use, what exact SoC you are talking about etc.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with programming? Shouldn't it be moved to SuperUser instead? Until you have a firmware and are programming using it, or editing its own code, then it seems off-topic for SO.

Comment: @underscore_d Is there an easy way to migrate it to SuperUser and pull the answers already here along with it?

Comment: @user_ABCD I believe you can flag it as such, though I don't know whether you can use the standard off-topic flag option that readers see. Maybe it would be best to raise a custom flag and request a moderator to move it for you; I think they'd be happy to oblige.

Comment: @underscore_d: I don't think this would really be on-topic for SuperUser. It is definitely a development question rather than a usage one. I don't suppose there is a "system design" site?

Answer (score 3):

First minor nit is that UEFI is just specification, what you using on platform is EDK2 or other UEFI spec implementation. So your vendor provide probably some EDK2 modification.

I think you have consider many factors:

- Implementation availability - as mentioned by Tom in other answer. This is key argument since most likely porting UEFI to new platform would be a significant programming effort.
- Target operating system - for modern Windows you don't have choice and you have to use EDK2
- Security type - note that new ARMv8 platform give certain security support (OP TEE, ATF) that you design may need to utilize.
- Feature set - to maximize ROI you will have choose implementation that have most of you features implemented.
- Contribution - U-Boot is clear about contribution terms and all code that is merged is under GPLv2, in case of any Tianocore project (which EDK2 is part of) you have to familiarize and sign off [TianoCore Contribution Agreement 1.0](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdePkg/Contributions.txt#L87). EDK2 is BSD-licensed.

I worked with both implementations EDK2 and U-Boot and if I will have choice I will go with U-Boot. Why ?

- Friendly, wide and diverse community - EDK2 rely mostly on Intel, Apple and couple commercial providers. U-Boot got people for various industries with various experience, so it is highly probable that someone had similar problems.
- Complexity -  learning curve for for UEFI/EDK2 is steep since they use various concepts that are not typical in embedded development (ie. HOBs, all the file types), for U-Boot anyone familiar with Linux kernel we quickly get design.
- Certification - AFAIK U-Boot do not have any formal process. For UEFI implementation you have set of tests to say you are UEFI complaint.

There are probably much more to that, but I think this is enough to do research by your own and realize what should be your choice.

Comment: EDK2 does not have its own license. The Tianocore project (which EDK2 is part of) does have a contribution agreement, but that is a different thing. For license, it does permit several BSD-like, with the default license being BSD 2-clause. There _was_ an issue specifically with the FAT filesystem driver in the past, but that was resolved earlier this year.

Comment: @unixsmurf you're right, I confused licensing with contribution agreement. Thanks for point this out - I will change my reply.